# Why is the overlay covering the new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a link button in an ASP.NET application as below. When i click the link button it calls Javascript function which shows another div file and the overlay. However, in this case, the overlay is appearing OVER the div instead of beneath it. Any guess on what could be wrong? I have copied this from another form which works fine.

```
<asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("CorrectiveActionName") %>'
                                    OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ProductionID", "return ShowCorrectiveActionDiv({0});") %>'
                                    runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtnCorrectiveAction_Click"
                                    CausesValidation="false" ID="lnkbtnCorrectiveAction">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
```

The javascript for ShowCorrectiveActionDiv is

```
function ShowCorrectiveActionDiv(objectid) {
    $("#divCorrectiveActionStatusChild").show();
    $(".overlay").show();
    var productionIdValue = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnProductionDIVID");
    productionIdValue.value = objectid;
    return true;
}
```

The CSS for overlay class is

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #083371;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

The overlay div in master page is

```
<div class="overlay" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: use z-index to overlay and new div

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa I added z-index as follows <div id="divCorrectiveActionStatusChild" class="dialogueWrap" style="z-index: 10">. Seems to work now.